# Invalid form key data - cannot login

Tags: magento-1.9, login, form-key

I just downloaded and installed the Full Release of Magento Community - ver 1.9.2.4, but I can't login in backend and frontend.

The error message is:

```
    Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.
```

I tried to clean the cache and sessions files of magento and of my browser, but doesn't work.

**Other things:**

- The file dont exist: 
  *app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php*
- The correct permissions was setup
- The form have keys for form_key
- On the frontend after login, i'm redirected for some page to ENABLE cookies.
- Table *core_config_data* dont have values for web/secure, web/unsecure, cookie_path and others, i create myself:
  [image: core_config_data]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you on localhost?

Comment: No! I'm in a Digital Ocean droplet running on NGINX, VARNISH

Comment: Please check your var/ folder is writable by the server, you can set it 777 permissions and check. Also folder must be owned by the web server user, for example www-data.

Comment: I try set 777 but yet doesnt work. All files and folders owned by www-data (configured in nginx) with right permissions.

Comment: Since you are on nginx make sure you have that line in your config `location \~\.php$ {
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "session.auto_start=0"; 
    #... more come here but I'm shortening just for the specific problem
}`

Comment: Try changing your session storage type in the local.xml config to db instead of files

Comment: @Goku Nothing happens, same problem. )):

Comment: @electroid Doesnt work )):

Comment: I see cookie_path but not cookie_domain

Answer (score 0):

clear your browser cache and cookies,

and after that delete the `var/cache` and `var/session` folder and try again login and let me know if you face this issue

Comment: Same problem, man. "Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page."

Answer (score 0):

you have to add form key in your login form
add this input tag

```
<"input type='hidden' name='form_key' value="<?php echo Mage:getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

in you form

refresh cache 
delete cache and session folder from var

Comment: I had tried it. Nothing)):

Comment: firstly you install magento in local. if it works fine than you upload file in server.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file app/etc/local.xml and find lines

```
<crypt>
    <key><![CDATA[9.....d]]></key>
</crypt>
```

try to change it to

```
<crypt>
    <key></key>
</crypt>
```

and then clean caches.

If it will not help - delete app/etc/local.xml file and reinstall magento from scratch. While installation - use your database name (as it's already installed) and installation will be quick.

Comment: I tried all but doesn't work. (including new installation)

Comment: So this can mean that Form Key is wrongly written to or readed from Session. Can you show session params in app/etc/local.xml ? is it saving session in files (/var/session) ?  If so - you can try to switch session to DB - to check if it's exactly the problem.

Comment: Other session options are Memcache and Redis. If some of them are used - maybe issue is somewhere in server configuration. I have problems with login/cookies sometimes too, but not with message "Invalid form key" and then I'm deleting Cookie Domain and Cookie Path in core_config_data table. Maybe it will help you somehow too